# Breeze modify data without ajax call; using signalR

Tags: angularjs, signalr, breeze

I'm working on a project which uses Angular, Breeze and signalR. I want to send data changes using SignalR instead of ajax calls from client side. How can I save changes in the breeze data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you planning to send the entire object graph or just individual objects?
In case of individual objects it should be as easy as attaching them to the DBContext. 
Object Graph will be another story.. don't even know how that will work with SignalR.